# Running VSCode headless, without installing desktop environment

Tags: debian, headless, visual-studio-code

Can you install VS-Code-CLI on a headless machine, without installing a desktop environment too?  (I sometimes wish to access my code on an Android tablet, using the PWA version of Code that doesn't allow ssh, only the VS Code tunnel.)

system spec:

```
No monitors, keyboards, speakers or anything.
Old Atom processor, 4G RAM
Debian 12 6.1.0-amd64 GCC 12.2
Node 20.1
```

Running `code` returns:

```
$ ./code 
No installation of Visual Studio Code stable was found.
Install it from your system's package manager or https://code.visualstudio.com, restart your shell, and try again.

If you already installed Visual Studio Code and we didn't detect it, run `code version use stable --install-dir /path/to/installation`
```

To install the Debian package `code_1.85.1-1702462158_amd64.deb`, depends on a display server, a window manager, a sound-subsystem, 1000s of libraries, etc. Which I don't need, or even want to attempt to install, on such a low-powered machine!  The same would apply to Raspberry Pi headless systems too.

The Debian package for `code`, depends on all these things.  Has anyone tried something different, or could the Debian package be split into, for example, `code-core` into `code-gui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a tunnel.

[The VScode documentation say](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview?WT.mc_id=social-reddit-aapowell#_remote-development-extension-pack):

> Remote - Tunnels - Connect to a remote machine via a secure tunnel, without configuring SSH

The installation:

```
curl -Lk 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=cli-alpine-x64' --output vscode_cli.tar.gz
tar -xf vscode_cli.tar.gz
rm vscode_cli.tar.gz
```

Then create the tunnel:

```
code tunnel
```

or

```
code tunnel --accept-server-license-terms
```

See [Using the 'code' CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels#_using-the-code-cli) for more details.

Comment: yes,  `code` fails to start without the gui installed, but `code tunnel` will start without the gui installed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could build vscodium from source. It needs some x11 libraries but not a whole desktop environment. See [the dependencies](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/docs/howto-build.md#dependencies-linux)

Follow [the instructions](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/docs/howto-build.md) to build vscodium from source, it should be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer with a full VS Code installed you can easily connect to the remote system (i.e. your headless machine) using the Remote-SSH VS Code extension. No additional installation of anything on the remote machine is required. Note that when you connect from your normal VS Code GUI to a remote machine for the first time, it will silently install a vscode server on the remote machine. Once connected you will have access to the remote machine file system, a shell terminal, and full editing experience of VS Code with all the extensions installed locally but working with the remote files.